# Ubuntu: large syslog and kern.log files

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, syslog

Logging into my Ubuntu machine, I get a warning that I am running out of disk space. Tracing back, I find that it is the syslogs, especially the kern.log(s) that are eating up my 1TB disk.

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 240G Feb 25 14:22 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 516G Feb 21 07:59 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1.1K Feb 15 07:39 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  19K Feb  7 07:56 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  37K Feb  1 07:45 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  23G Feb 25 14:52 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  25G Feb 25 08:11 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1.6G Feb 24 07:49 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1.7G Feb 23 08:18 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 3.4G Feb 22 08:19 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 3.6G Feb 21 07:59 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 6.9G Feb 20 07:38 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 7.3G Feb 19 07:36 syslog.7.gz
```

From the snippet above, you can easily find that kern.log and kern.log.1 is eating up 80% of my 1TB disk. I can get the space by deleting the files, but I think it won't solve the problem.

Does anyone have an idea on what the issue might be?
I saw that you can get the logging level by:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

and I get

```
4    4    1    7
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a  programming question. It is more suitable for [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: This question seems to have a really nice (and more complete than any was given here) answer at askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/184949/how-do-i-limit-the-size-of-my-syslog

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have you checked the content of those files? There's obviously something going on with your server causing events to be generated. Resolve whatever issue is causing that, and your logs should return to their normal size.

To temporary solve the issue, type

```
echo "" > /var/log/kern.log
echo "" > /var/log/syslog
service syslog restart
journalctl --vacuum-size=50M
```

You need to be root user for this: enter `sudo su`, your password, and then the above commands

Comment: This one saved my life! +1

Comment: `sudo su` should be used first, otherwise,  `service syslog restart` may not work

Answer (score 153):

This is an old question, but neither of the previous two answers are good solutions:

- The accepted answer doesn't explain why the disk problem goes away if you fix the underlying system issue (the answer is `logrotate`), plus your system may keep writing to the logs and fill up your disk before you can even figure out the underlying issue.
- The other answer removes and disables the logs entirely, which is not a good approach as it ignores the underlying issue. Also, you'll probably want those log files later when you're figuring out other system problems -- disabling `syslog` makes it more difficult to track down future issues!

Instead, here is a safer method that lets you keep the log files while reclaiming disk space while also stopping the log files from doing this again.

1. Safely clear the logs: after looking at (or backing up) the logs to identify your system's problem, clear them by typing `> /var/log/syslog` (including the `>`). You may need to be root user for this, in which case enter `sudo su`, your password, and then the above command).

- Then restart the syslog service (either `systemctl restart syslog` or `service syslog restart`).

2. Then, you can force the logs to rotate and delete automatically if they reach a certain size, using `logrotate`. In this case you can edit the config with `sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` and add one line:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    maxsize 1G # add this line
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
}
```

- This will force your `syslog` to "rotate" (i.e., create a new log file and archive the previous log file) after either 1 day or when the file becomes 1GB, whichever comes first. Note that `rotate 7` means your system will only keep 7 total `syslog` backups so it can only ever take up 7GB of space
- Note: you can change `maxsize`, `rotate N`, and other settings to customize your logs -- use the command `man logrotate` to see more.

3. While you're at it, you may want to add the same setting in the second part of the file, which governs the behavior of other log files (e.g. `kern.log` for kernel events, `auth.log` for authentication events, etc.). This setting will make it so that each of these other log files will only take 4GB in total.:

```
...
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    maxsize 1G
...
}
```

This will allow your system to keep logging events without them filling your disk.

For more, see the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) and a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239455/how-do-i-stop-var-log-kern-log-1-from-consuming-all-my-disk-space).

Comment: If the size is generated during one day, this is not a solution, because logrotate only runs once a day. To run logrotate hourly instead of daily, you can move it: `mv /etc/cron.daily/logrotate /etc/cron.hourly/`

Comment: Is `maxsize` a typo for `size`? According to [the man page for logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate), under the section "Configuration File", it states that `size` and `minsize` are both valid directives, but there is no mention of `maxsize` (and furthermore, setting `maxsize` in `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` did not solve my problem with large log files, I am going to try setting `size` instead and time will tell if this works or not)

Comment: @JakeLevi It's not a typo (I have `maxsize` successfully working with my local logrotate config), but you're correct that it's not specified in the online manpage. It still shows up on my system when running `man logrotate` so I'd expect it to be a version issue, though I do not see anything about this in the [logrotate changelog](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/master/ChangeLog.md). I will post my local manual entry for `maxsize`, which suggests that the log would be rotated even before the time interval (avoiding the issue mentioned by @rubo77)

Comment: **maxsize** _size_:
        `Log  files are rotated when they grow bigger than size bytes even before the additionally specified time interval (daily, weekly, monthly, or yearly).  The related size option is similar except that it is mutually exclusive with the time interval options, and it causes log files to be rotated without regard for the last rotation time.  When maxsize  is  used,  both the size and timestamp of a log file are considered.`

Comment: I checked running `man logrotate` locally and you're right, there is a `maxsize` directive that's not on the online manpage for some reason

Comment: `maxsize` didn't have the desired behaviour for me for some reason (using `logrotate` version 3.14.0), but I managed to get the desired behaviour by using `size 100M`, and removing all time-based directives (`daily`, `weekly` etc) from the `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` configurations in `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`. I also used `sudo mv /etc/cron.daily/logrotate /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` to make rotation happen hourly instead of daily, as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/851038/620693)

Answer (score 11):

- Rotation of log files (EG system logs, kernel logs) is handled by `logrotate`
- Enter the following command to modify the `logrotate` configurations:

```
sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

- Under the entries for the log files that are reaching problematic sizes (EG `syslog`, `kern.log`), if there is no configuration then add the configuration shown below, otherwise modify the existing configuration to look like the configuration shown below
- A configuration consists of one or more lines of directives enclosed in curly braces, type `man logrotate` and scroll down to the `DIRECTIVES` section for a description of these directives
- In particular, make sure to include the `size 100M` line, where `100M` can be modified according to the maximum size you want your log files to take up, and make sure that there are no time-based rotation directives, EG `daily`, `weekly`, etc

```
{
        rotate 7
        size 100M
        missingok
        ifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}
```

- Rotation of log files can be scheduled by `cron`, and by default happens daily
- You can modify this behaviour to schedule rotation of log files to happen hourly instead of daily using the following command:

```
sudo mv /etc/cron.daily/logrotate /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate
```

- It is possible that the `cron` script for `logrotate` is disabled in favour of the `systemd` timer
- You can make sure that the `cron` script for `logrotate` is not disabled in favour of the `systemd` timer as follows:

  - Enter the command `sudo nano /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` to view the contents of the `cron` script for `logrotate` (or `sudo nano /etc/cron.daily/logrotate` if you didn't previously move the script)
  - Check to see if the following four lines are present, and if they are, either comment them out by placing a `#` at the beginning of each line, or delete those lines entirely:

```
# skip in favour of systemd timer
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

- You can also manually force rotation of log files using the following command:

```
sudo logrotate --force --verbose /etc/logrotate.conf
```

- To simply see what actions would be performed by the above command, without actually rotating or removing any log files, use the following command:

```
sudo logrotate --force --debug /etc/logrotate.conf
```

- If you find that the `/var/log/journal` folder is also getting very big, according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238221/1078405), you can clear it with the following command:

```
sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=100M
```

- To make this happen automatically every time `logrotate` is called by `cron`, enter the command `sudo nano /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` (or `sudo nano /etc/cron.daily/logrotate` if you didn't previously move the script) and insert the line `journalctl --vacuum-size=100M` (NB not including `sudo`)

Comment: I realize this is closed but this should be the accepted answer, it is comprehensive and includes elimnating the systemd timer issue that trips most people up.

Answer (score 1):

As [ascendants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9161344/ascendants) suggests: "Safely clear the logs: after looking at (or backing up) the logs to identify your system's problem"

The ***real problem*** was found in the logsys file: millions of lines with the following message "PCIe Bus Error severity Corrected".

The "PCIe Bus Error severity Corrected" error is basically a Linux report indicating that there is some problem, in my case hardware compatibility.

This problem caused several files or folders to grow out of proportion (30 GB or more): `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/journal/`, etc.

On [this site](https://itsfoss.com/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected/)  they offer four solutions that offer a workaround, in my case only the last option worked for me.