# How to limit size of or logrotate php-fph access.log file?

Tags: php, logging

I've inherited a php-fpm based EC2 webserver. The `wordpress.access.log` file in EC2 is almost 2GB and is eating up the drive. I'd like to limit it's size somehow.

My `php_fpm_site.conf` has `access.log = /var/log/$pool.access.log`, but I can't find a setting to roll over or limit the log filesize.

Comment: You need to find where your logrotate settings are stored. On my Ubuntu servers it is in `/etc/logrotate.d/`. You can then follow standard logrotate things like `maxsize`, `daily`, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23728801/231316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the logrotate configuration file for your custom wordpress access log.
create file in `/etc/logrotated.d/wordpress_access`

```
/var/log/wordpress.access.log {
    rotate 4
    size 500M
    missingok
    nodateext
    compress
}
```

With this configuration your log file will be rotated when hit 500MB and will keep 4 compressed copies of the log, note that by default logrotate has been triggered once per day, by `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` .
There is an option to schedule cron.hourly if you want logrotate ran on hourly base.

Comment: This is essentially what I did to fix the issue